# Can i call controller's function from my javascript which is in assets folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using ruby on rails for my project. I have 4 folders in my app folder  models,views,controller and assets. In assets folder i have  javascript code which  runs whenever i opens my website . So can i call my controller function from my javascript which is in /rails-roots/app/assets/javascript/b.js.erb . i tried an ajax call but it didn't work . 
like i have method_A in controller which is returning a array of map . path for my method_A is  /rails-roots/app/controller/Beam/index_controller.rb

Comment: Please show your code and what you tried

Comment: No , my question  that  can we call Method_A which is in controller from assets javascript . i just want the return value of this function Method_A . Answer below is showing the error : undefined var IndexController.So please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

In an erb file you can call every ruby function with

```
<%= IndexController.method_A %>
```

A file called b.js.erb is evaluated from right to left, that means, first the erb-part (like your method call), then the js-part.

Comment: getting this error :"uninitialized constant IndexController "

Comment: this was just an example!

Comment: method_A is static in controller "self."
so we need not to make its object . then how should i call the function ?
i just need the return values of  method_A . method _A is doing some manipulations in model so i cannot define this function anywhere else